# How to substract raster1 and raster2 in rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I have tried to subtract the `raster1.tif` and `raster2.tif` using rasterio in python. The `raster1.tif` file is larger and completely overlaps the `raster2.tif`.

I need to subtract `raster1.tif - raster2.tif` in such a way so that the output raster extent will be equal to `raster1.tif`.

I have written the following code,

```py
import rasterio 

with rasterio.open('raster1.tif') as src1, rasterio.open('raster2.tif') as src2:
    data1 = src1.read(1)
    data2 = src2.read(1)
    data = data1 - data2

    with rasterio.open("output.tif", 'w', **src1.meta) as dst:
        dst.write(data,1)
```

It produces the following error,

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (790,1554) (57,67)
```

I know this error is generated since both my raster has different bounds. Can anyone help me to fix this issue? is there any way to reshape the `data2` so I can subtract easily?

> **PS:** I have reproduced the required thing with ArcGIS Pro using a raster calculator with the condition below,

```sql
Con(IsNull('raster2.tif'), 'raster1.tif', 'raster1.tif' - 'raster2.tif')
```

> I am looking for the equivalent code in `rasterio`.

[image: Image showing raster1 and raster2]

Comment: If the two images are of different sizes, what does it mean to subtract them?  Do you want to subtract starting at the upper left of the larger image?  Centered?  Repeated?  There is no well-defined meaning to the concept.

Comment: The `raster1.tif` completely overlaps the `raster2.tif` file (As shown in the above image). I want to subtract the value of `raster2.tif` from `raster1.tif`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question in any way.  You have somewhat arbitrarily placed raster2.tif in the middle of the image.  Where, exactly?  How would that be decided?  You can't subtract a 4x4 matrix from a 100x100 matrix unless you know WHERE in the matrix you're going to do the subtraction.

Comment: Both are georeferenced rasters. If we open the file in geospatial software like ArcGIS or qgis, it will overlap like the above image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully implemented the solution code as below after an hours of trial and errors. Thank you everyone,

```py
with rasterio.open('raster1.tif') as src1, rasterio.open('raster2.tif') as src2:
    data1 = src1.read(1)

    # extract metadata from the first raster
    meta = src1.meta.copy()

    # read the window of the second raster with the same extent as the first raster
    window = src2.window(*src1.bounds)

    # read the data from the second raster with the same window as first raster
    data2 = src2.read(1, window=window, boundless=True, fill_value=0)
    data2 = np.where(data2 == src2.nodata, 0, data2)

    # calculate the difference
    data = data1 - data2

    # write the result to a new raster
    with rasterio.open("output.tif", 'w', **meta) as dst:
        dst.write(data,1)
```